# Flash attributes and ResourceBundleViewResolver

Tags: spring

I am facing an issue with the flash attributes which I have not able to retrieve it in the GET phase of POST/redirect/GET scenario. This is only happening when I use the ResourceBundleViewResolver.

### view resolver

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ResourceBundleViewResolver"> 
    <property name="basename" value="spring-views" /> </bean>
```

### view properties

```
form.(class)=org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView
form.url=/WEB-INF/pages/form.jsp

home.(class)=org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView
home.url=/WEB-INF/pages/home.jsp

home_redirect.(class)=org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView
home_redirect.url=home
```

### form.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>


    <form action="register" method="post">
       Name:   <input type="text" name="name"/> <br/>

       <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

### home.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

<html>
<body>

   <h2>  ${status} </h2>

</body>
</html>
```

so in this page, home.jsp, the status should contain the value set as the flash attribute.

### controller

```
@Controller
public class WebController {


    @RequestMapping(value="/form", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showFormPage(){
        return "form";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/register", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView login(@RequestParam("name") String name, RedirectAttributes flashMap){
        System.out.println("name = " + name);
        flashMap.addFlashAttribute("status", "Registered successfully");        
        //return new RedirectView("home"); -- with this returned its working 
        return new ModelAndView("home_redirect");  //-- with this returned its not working 
        //return "redirect:home"; // -- not working
    }


    @RequestMapping(value="/home")  
    public String showHomePage(){
        return "home";
    }
}
```

on the whole this is the observation made:

if used resource bundle view resolver

1. return view names as string - not working
2. return ModelAndView - not working
3. return RedirectAndView - working

if used internal view resolver

1. return view names as string - working
   2  return modelandview - cannot be used to redirect
2. return RedirectAndView - working

Comment: What is the probem? What is the expected behavoir, and what happend instead?

Comment: Do you have any documentation for the 2. case? I never heard of a feature where one can redirect in this way

Comment: sorry, a typo. Changed case 2, where I am returning ModelAndView.

Comment: expeceted behaviour for all the cases should be that in the second handler (/home), the RedirectAttributes, the flash params should work which is not working.